# Python HTML parsing: removing excess HTML from get request output

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping

I am wanting to make a simple python script to automate the process of pulling .mov files from an IP camera's SD card. The Model of IP camera supports http requests which returns HTML that contains the .mov file info. My python script so far..

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
page = requests.get("http://192.168.1.99/form/getStorageFileList?type=3")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
```

OUTPUT:

```
NAME2041=Record_continiously/2018-06-02/8/MP_2018-06-03_00-33-15_60.mov
```

I want to only return the MOV file. So removing:

```
"NAME2041=Record_continiously/2018-06-02/8/"
```

I'm new to HTML parsing with python so I'm a bit confused with the functionality.

Is returned HTML considered a string? If so, I understand that it will be immutable and I will have to create a new string instead of "striping away" the preexisting string.

I have tried:

```
page.replace("NAME2041=Record_continiously/2018-06-02/8/","")
```

in which I receive an attribute error. Is anyone aware of any method that could accomplish this?

Here is a sample of the HTML I am working with...

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
000 Success NUM=2039 NAME0=Record_Continuously/2018-06-04/10/MP_2018-06-04_12-17-38_60.mov SIZE0=15736218 
NAME1=Record_Continuously/2018-06-04/10/MP_2018-06-04_12-16-37_60.mov SIZE1=15683077
NAME2=Record_Continuously/2018-06-04/10/MP_2018-06-04_12-15-36_60.mov SIZE2=15676882
NAME3=Record_Continuously/2018-06-04/10/MP_2018-06-04_12-14-35_60.mov SIZE3=15731539 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `str.split` with negative indexing.

**Ex:**

```
page = "NAME2041=Record_continiously/2018-06-02/8/MP_2018-06-03_00-33-15_60.mov"
print( page.split("/")[-1])
```

**Output:**

```
MP_2018-06-03_00-33-15_60.mov
```

Comment: Thank you! this worked. The only thing is, there will be hundreds of these strings coming in as the camera captures events, all with different times and dates. How can I use this method across multiple cameras and .mov clips?

Comment: Can you show a sample of your data. are these string in a list?

Comment: the returned data after making get request is just simple HTML. Only having HTML tags and a body tag, Its pretty messy unless I view source or prettify with bs4. I'm assuming the data is in a list but Im not sure due to inexperience. here is the data: 000 Success
NUM=2039
NAME0=Record_Continuously/2018-06-04/10/MP_2018-06-04_12-17-38_60.mov
SIZE0=15736218
NAME1=Record_Continuously/2018-06-04/10/MP_2018-06-04_12-16-37_60.mov
SIZE1=15683077
NAME2=Record_Continuously/2018-06-04/10/MP_2018-06-04_12-15-36_60.mov
SIZE2=15676882

Comment: Can you post the html in your question?

Comment: Sure no problem, I went ahead and edited my question with the HTML I am working with.

Answer (score 0):

as you asked for explanation of your code here it is:

```
# import statements
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
import requests

page = requests.get("http://192.168.1.99/form/getStorageFileList?type=3")  # returns response object
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')  #
```

`page.content` returns string content of response

you are passing this(`page.content`) string content to class `BeautifulSoup` which is initialized with two arguments your content(`page.content`) as string and parser here it is `html.parser`

`soup` is the object of `BeautifulSoup`

`.prettify()` is method used to pretty print the content

In string slicing you may get failure of result due to length of content so it's better to split your content as suggested by @Rakesh and that's the best approach in your case.